# Count posts that have specific taxonomy term attached

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms, count

When upgrading our portfolio I'm looking for something that shows the number of posts in a (current) category of a post type.

Example: I have a category with 'features'. Each feature has it's own description, apps related and blog related posts page

I'm fetching the current category with:

```
<?php $cat_id = get_query_var('cat'); ?>
```

and get posts with:

```
 <?php query_posts("post_type=apps&cat=$cat_id&showposts=3");?>
```

How is it possible to count the posts of post_type=apps and category=$cat_id ?

I'm sorry for my lack of PHP/WP experience.. does anyone know how to get these 2 things working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, don't use `query_posts()`, second, please ask the second question as new question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Public API for the rescue

`category` is a Taxonomy that's already built in. Therefore it's quite easy to get its term count with [`get_terms( $tax, array( /* args */ ) );`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_terms/)

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'fields' => 'count',
) );
```

This will do a pretty fast `COUNT (*)` query so you don't have to worry about performance.

### Alternate solution

You could as well just do a normal call to `get_terms()` and then alter the `selects` with the filter:

```
// The core filter:
apply_filters( 'get_terms_fields', $selects, $args )

// Example callback:
add_action( 'get_terms_fields', 'wpse105174_get_terms_fields_cb', 10, 2 );
function wpse105174_get_terms_fields_cb( $selects, $args )
{
    return array( 't.term_id', 'COUNT(*)' );
}
```

...where `$selects` is aan array (which will be imploded to a comma separated string).

### Making it even faster

You could then further modify the query and restrict it to only some specific categories (terms/taxons) with a `WHERE t.slug = whatever`

```
// The core filter:
apply_filters( 'terms_clauses', compact( $pieces ), $taxonomies, $args );

// Example callback:
add_action( 'terms_clauses', 'wpse105174_terms_clauses_cb', 10, 3 );
function wpse105174_terms_clauses_cb( $pieces, $taxonomies, $args )
{
    $pieces['where'] = " WHERE t.slug = whatever";
    // Or do some `str_replace`, `preg_replace`, whatever fits in here

    return $pieces;
}
```

You could set the `$pieces['join'] = '';` as well if you don't need access to the `term_taxonomy`-table.

### Cache it

Finally you could utilize the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to save your results (as serialized array) to the DB, so you don't have to query the count every time you need it.

Comment: Hey Kaiser,

Thanks for the detailed answer. Problem is I'm not a PHP'er so most of this part I didn't really get..

Comment: @rwzdoorn Well, you got full examples there. Just try it? :)

Comment: @kaiser, is digging into SQL the only way in WP to do further taxonomy filtering: number of tags used within a certain category (as per your example above)?

Answer (score 2):

The count of posts is cached in category object for things like this. In category archivve something like this should be easiest:

```
$category = get_queried_object();
// $category->count has count
```

If you are trying to retrieve all posts in category via that loop you should be using `posts_per_page=-1`, `-1` for all and `posts_per_page` is newer replacement for `showposts`.

To create links to category archive you can use [`get_category_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_category_link/) function.

Answer (score 1):

Had some trouble in the beginning but this works for me:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts("post_type=apps&cat=$cat_id"); 
$count = count($posts); 
 echo "$count"; 
?>
```

Comment: Did you try one of the recommendations above? Or care to comment on them why they didn't work for you?

Answer (score -1):

You can have post count from $post variable after query_posts as

```
query_posts("post_type=apps&cat=$cat_id&showposts=3");
echo $post->post_count;
```

You are in a category page I suppose since you are obtaining category id from get_query_var('cat'). So, what do you really want for more than three posts? can you explain it?

Comment: HI MD,

The echo $post->post_count; isn't working for me. We have a 'feature' list of related apps we created. If there are more then 3 i'd like to create a button to 'all apps related to feature X'